# Discord Bot isn't playing music

Tags: audio, discord, audio-player, discord.py

I have been following a discord bot tutorial from 2 years ago. As you know, they reworked discord.py and after about an hour of searching I have found people with the same issue but no answer.I keep getting "AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ytdl_player'". If anyone has anything, it would be appreciated.

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def play(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player("https://youtu.be/HKe1jFjojzA")
    players[guild.id] = player
    player.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using syntax from a previous version of discord.py, which doesn’t work anymore. 
Have a look at the [changes](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#voice-changes) made when discord.py migrated to v1.

**EDIT:**
[Here's](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py) an example